# Why moment is adding one hour?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

When I use:

```
console.log(moment(1000*60*60*1).format('hh[h] mm[min] ss[sec]'));
```

I get 2h 0min 0sec instead of just 1hour. 
I made a workaround by adding .subtract(1, 'hour') like this:

```
console.log(moment(1000*60*60*1).subtract(1, 'hour').format('hh[h] mm[min] ss[sec]'));
```

I'm still learning this library that i found today. Am I missing something? 
What am I supposed to do if I have milliseconds and I want to get a formatted date out of it?

Comment: are you in a timezone that is UTC+1 perhaps

Comment: Yes, but it does matter?

Comment: for me your code returns `06h 30min 00sec`

Comment: so, the +1 hour of your timezone isn't a clue as to what is going on? ...

Comment: I've tried and it's the timezone that matters

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moment counts your timezone, to get the time without timezone offset you can use

```
moment(1000*60*60*1).utc().format('hh[h] mm[min] ss[sec]')
```

Or

```
moment.utc(1000*60*60*1).format('hh[h] mm[min] ss[sec]')
```

Comment: I am at GMT+6 but moment.format() adds 12 hours. moment.utc().format() adds 6. any suggestions why?